# Run quartz every n>60 minutes

Tags: cron, quartz-scheduler

How do I run quartz every n minutes, where n is greater than 60? Let's say I want to run quartz every 100 minutes, how do I do it?

As observed, 0 0/100 * * * ? *, also runs on the 60th minute.

Comment: I think you misunderstood what that string means. It doesn't just specify how often to run. It also specifies WHEN to run. Its saying every time the minute is divisible by 100. Which only occurs when the minute is 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is where the [DailyTimeIntervalTrigger](http://javadox.com/org.quartz-scheduler/quartz/2.2.1/org/quartz/impl/triggers/DailyTimeIntervalTriggerImpl.html) (Quartz 2.x), or DateIntervalTrigger (Quartz 1.8.x) are typically used.

I am attaching a screenshot from our [QuartzDesk](http://www.quartzdesk.com) app that depicts a sample DailyTimeIntervalTrigger configuration for your scenario (i.e. job triggered every 100 minutes - in addition to that the example trigger configuration limits the job execution on work days and time between 8am and 6pm).

[image: Sample DailyTimeIntervalTrigger Configuration In Quartzdesk]